# How to make the jQuery modal dialog boxes show once a day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, setcookie, jquery-cookie

i have jQuery modal dialog boxes, witch is opening automatically and have setTimeout:

```
function showChat() { $(function(){
    $('#chat').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        show: 'fade',
        hide: 'fade',
        width: 400,
        height: 250,
         open: function(event, ui){
           setTimeout("$('#chatnsp').dialog('close')",30000);
        }
    }); });        } showChatp();

<a onclick="showChatnsp(); return false;"><div style="display:none; "> </div></a> <div id="chatnsp" title=" "  style="display:none; ">   TEXT </div>
```

How to make the modal window show once a day?

Found this code, but could not connect:

```
<script src="http://yastatic.net/jquery/cookie/1.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    if (!$.cookie('hideModal')) {
    var delay_popup = 5000;
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='block'", delay_popup);
    }
    $.cookie('hideModal', true, {
        expires: 1,
        path: '/'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try replacing `"document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='block'"` with `showChat`

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Can you show a complete example of how you are trying to use the cookie code to work with your existing code?